# Input a 128-bit value c++ boost

Tags: c++, boost, multiprecision

I use `int128_t` in boost, multiprecision library.

When I write `int128_t number = 265252859812191058636308480000000;`
I have a mistake, that constant is too long.

How can I input 128-bit value correctly?
For example:

`AF5228967057FE1CB84B92511BE89A47` in int128_t?

Comment: Certainly there would be an example of initializing a variable of this type  in the boost documentation?

Comment: I cannot find how to initialize this variable. Can you please write a url?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As @jonathon-reinhart said, a bit of reading the boost documentation will lead you to an answer.

Specifically, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/conversions.html shows how to construct multi precision types from (say) a string.

You can't construct it from a literal, because literals are only built-in types. Unless you are using C++11 and you have a compiler which supports user-defined literal conversions, in which case http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/lits.html describes how to use those.